# Register menu wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, registration

I have the menu list a "Register", and when the user was logged, the "Register" menu disappears.

How can I do this?

I created the menu by using Appearance -> Menus

Comment: How can someone understand this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your theme to achieve this:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo '<a class="register-menu" href="#">Register</a>'; //make sure to add the correct link there.
}
?>
```

You can customize this link style using the class `.register-menu`